# How can I make the ball go where it is supposed to go after it is hit by the stick?

Tags: java, game-development

I am trying to work on a 3 cushion Billiards game nowadays. I am having a slight problem. I after I release the mouse to hit the ball with the stick, the ball doesn't go where it is supposed to go.

What will be the best approach to solve this problem?

I tried using `mouseX` and `mouseY` in the formula which makes the ball go wherever it is supposed to go. But it only works for one quadrant. The ball mostly goes to the upper left corner of the `JFrame`.

I have a feeling that I need to use multiple `if` statements and a variable called `angle`, but I am not sure how.

```
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
{
    LineDraw = false; 
    MouseDragged = false; 
    WHITExSpeed = -mouseX * 0.005; 
    WHITEySpeed = -mouseY * 0.005; 
    //repaint(); 
}

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) 
{
    LineDraw = true; 
    MouseDragged = true; 
    mouseX = e.getX();
    mouseY = e.getY(); 
    repaint(); 
}
...
//This if statement in is paintCompoment
if(LineDraw)
{
    Line2D.Double Stick = new Line2D.Double(white.getCenterX(),white.getCenterY(), mouseX, mouseY);
    g2d.setColor(Stick_Color);
    g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
    g2d.draw(Stick);
}
```

The ball must go wherever the stick was facing after the mouse button is released.

Comment: the speed of your ball is `WHITEySpeed` and `WHITExSpeed` I presume?

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem lies in the `WHITExSpeed`/`WHITEySpeed`.

You don't calculate the delta from the mouse position to the white ball there.

Shouldn't it be following?

```
WHITExSpeed = (mouseX - white.getCenterX()) * 0.005; 
WHITEySpeed = (mouseY - white.getCenterY()) * 0.005;
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I multiplied both of your equations to make the ball go where the stick was facing. Otherwise, it was going towards the stick. You saved my life. Thanks